# Calculating a limit as a consequence of the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. I have to calculate for all $a>0$ this: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^n \frac{n^2  x e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2} d\lambda(x)$$ as an excercise of my Measure Theory lessons.

As an instruction, the excercise says that it follows by delimiting the sequence below the integral and applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem. In order to do this, I have tried to use the inequality $\forall y \in \Bbb{R} : 1 + y \leq e^y$ but I am not reaching any point and I have no more ideas.

Any advice? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a positive $t$, one has $e^t\geqslant t $ hence
$$
\frac{n^2  x e^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2} \mathbf{1}_{[a,n]}(x)\leqslant \frac{1}{1+x^2}n^2(n^2x^2)^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{[a,n]}(x)\leqslant \frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)}\mathbf{1}_{[a,\infty)}(x).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The limit can also be obtained as an application of the following version of dominated convergence:

> If $|f_n|\leq g_n$, $(g_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset L_1$, $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$, $g_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g$ and $\lim_n\int g_n=\int g$, then $$\lim_n\int f_n=\int f$$

In the OP's example
$$0\leq I_n =\int^n_a\frac{n^2xe^{-(nx)^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx\leq\int^n_a n^2xe^{-(nx)^2}\,dx=-\frac{n}2e^{-(nx)^2}\Big|^n_a=\frac{ne^{-a^2n^2}-ne^{-n^4}}{2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is perfect

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ For $a > \frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}$ and $n > \frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2} < \frac{n^2ae^{-n^2a^2}}{1+x^2} < \frac{1}{a^2e}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

which is integrable on $[a,\infty)$

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstunding something but, if the integral is in the interval $(a, n)$, don't we have $a < x$ so the first inequality is false?

Comment: @Superdivinidad the function is decreasing so long as the first condition holds so $a<x$ is what we want.

Comment: @Superdivinidad I think you've managed to confuse yourself here. The statement I have written is indeed true, feel free to plot it for yourself.

Comment: You are totally right, I mistake something on what I write, sorry for the misunderstunding